# How to get device name like "whyred" for Xiaomi Redmi Note 5?

Tags: custom-roms, lineageos, xiaomi, device-name

For custom ROMs like LineageOS, the more specific device names are used. So e.g. the Xiaomi Redmi Note 5 is called [whyred](https://download.lineageos.org/whyred) or Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge goes [hero2lte](https://download.lineageos.org/hero2lte). Having some experience in Android and custom ROMs, I don't know how to find out device names based on the colloquially used device names (Redmi Note 5 -> whyred).

Neither in specs on e.g. shop sites, nor in the device info. Let's look at the device info  of a Xiaomi Redmi Note 5 Pro:

[image]

I only see `M1803E7SG` as the model name here but does not match the device name used for custom ROMs. Especially on Xiaomi, it's a big mess to get rich in different models or editions. Sometimes a single model is not equal across different regions.

For `M1803E7SG`, I found [this article](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Test-Xiaomi-Redmi-Note-5-Smartphone.313368.0.html) which says:

> For reference, our review unit is the M1803E7SG. This is also known a the Redmi Note 5 AI Dual Camera. It is neither the Redmi 5 Plus, which is listed as the Redmi Note 5 on Xiaomi's Mi website, nor is it the Redmi Note 5 Pro either. All three devices are powered by a Qualcomm Snapdragon 636 SoC, but they feature different camera hardware and memory options among other differences.

So, is this a flashable device for TWRP/LineageOS? I'm really confused now and would like to see the device name for this smartphone.

Comment: As long as it's on SDM636 you should be fine. The main confusion here is Redmi 5 Plus (`vince`) which has an SD625 inside, but often confused due to its Indian naming.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, you can either find the device codename from the [official Xiaomi forum](http://en.miui.com/thread-644392-1-1.html) (which I believe is constantly updated). You can also use a third-party tool [Device ID](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.redphx.deviceid) to get your device codename:

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to a terminal (either adb or a terminal app) then just run:

```
getprop ro.product.device
```

or you can run `getprop` by itself to get all sorts of good information

Answer (score 0):

## Xiaomi specific

Dial `*#*#64663#*#*` and use `1 Check version info`. Near *Camera information* you can see the codename.

### Vendor unspecific

You could use Device ID as xavier_fakerat already suggested. But I also found [aida64](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.finalwire.aida64) which seems more verbose as you can see much more details about the device instead of only seeing the Device ID. But if you're really just want the codename, the Device Id app works well.